# How to align fontawesome icons to the middle

Tags: html, css

[image]Hi I got a problem with aligning 3 icons. I want to align them but everytime I try something like this the first icon starts from the middle of the page but I want there the 2nd icon.

```css
.item-icon {
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.item-image {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan">
  <div class="item-icon">
    <div class="item-image">
      <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-icon">
    <div class="item-image">
      <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-icon">
    <div class="item-image">
      <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-text">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code has an unclosed `div`. Fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

add these rules
it's a little bit tricky though.

for `div.plan`

```
.plan {
    font-size 0:
}
```

for `div.item-icon`

```
.item-icon {
        width: 33.33333%;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you give an image describing what you are intending to do, that whould help a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I added the pic

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: Did you give the .item-icon a display: inline-block; ? If no, try to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try margin: auto instead of setting width. Should automatically adjust margins on each side to center it.

```
.item-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    }

.item-image {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.plan {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Try changing item icon to plan, which is your parent div

Comment: edited my answer.  I tried it on my end and it worked.  hopefully it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.plan {
  text-align: center;
}

.item-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Because it`s just css

Comment: Then why is it a snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
.plan {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px 0; // optional vertical padding
    margin: 0 -24px; // optional horizontal padding  offset
}

.item-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 24px; // optional horizontal padding
}
```

https://codepen.io/themeler/pen/QQoGMa

You've tried to center icon inside icon container (`.item-icon`) but container has size of an icon, so it won't work as you expect. Also you tried positioning each icon 50% from left and top. That won't work either.

`.plan` should be your icon container with centered text and icons displayed as 'inline-block's so centering will affect them.

I've added additional padding to both `.plan` (vertical padding) and icon containers themselves (horizontal padding, to keep them separate).